# Object Reference Error filling a datarow

Tags: datatable, dataset, datarow, datatable.select

This is the code:

```
Dim dr() As DataRow = DataSet.Tables("TableName").Select("EVENTNAME = '" & name & "'")
```

I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Error when this line is executed.  It is looping through a list of selected items in a listbox.  I think it has to do with how I have the datarow declared because I can look at the name and I see it ok and I also do a null check on the name before I use it.

Visual Studio 2008, VB.NET.  Any ideas?

---

Yep it was a wrong table name.  I guess after looking at the code for 8 hours that minor detail I just wasn't thinking to check.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have the wrong `"TableName"`.

Comment: I checked; a non-existent name will return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like it is the select statement:

vm_DataTable_SELECT_string = "[MyField] = '" + vm_TEXT_string + "'"; 
DataRow[] o_DataRow_ARRAY_Found = vco_DataTable.Select (vm_DataTable_SELECT_string);